# loading views with shortend names codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For less typing of the views in my $data variables. I would like just the view to be able to pick up common/file_name rather than tying in full length and same for my if statement

Is there a function in a library or custom library that could make this work I just don't want to have to put in full view name only the last to segments foldername/file

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {


public function index(){
$data['column_left'] = $this->load->view('common/column_left');
$data['column_right'] = $this->load->view('common/column_right');
$data['content_top'] = $this->load->view('common/content_top');
$data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->view('common/content_bottom');
$data['footer'] = $this->load->view('common/footer');
$data['header'] = $this->load->view('common/header');

if(file_exists('template/common/home.tpl')) { // can't get it to pick up file in theme
     $this->load->view('template/common/home.tpl', $data);
} else {
     $this->load->view('default/template/common/home.tpl', $data); // theme
}
}
}
```

Comment: Not there isn't. You have to write your own library (or helper) by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with custom `library`. This is general tip from my old answer. You can change as per your need. You can pass your theme from `controller` or from `config`.

Create a new library file called `template.php` and write a function called load_template. In that function, use above code.

```
public function load_template($view_file_name,$data_array=array()) {

$ci = &get_instatnce();

$ci->load->view("header");

$ci->load->view($view_file_name,$data_array);

$ci->> load->view("footer");

}
```

You have to load this library in autoload file in config folder. **so you don't want to load in all controller.**

You can this function like

```
$this->template->load_template("index");
```

If you want to pass date to view file, then you can send via $data_array

Answer (score 0):

Yes! it is (a way how to make this work), extend your Controller via MY_Controller.php (in /application/core/)

it should look like this

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    protected $data = Array();

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->output->enable_profiler(FALSE);
    }

    public function _render() { //as I understand now you dont need parameter

        $template['column_left'] = $this->load->view('common/column_left', '', TRUE);
        $template['column_right'] = $this->load->view('common/column_right', '', TRUE);
        $template['content_top'] = $this->load->view('common/content_top', '', TRUE);
        $template['content_bottom'] = $this->load->view('common/content_bottom', '', TRUE);
        //$this->load->view($view_file, $this->data);
        $template['footer'] = $this->load->view('common/footer', '', TRUE);
        $template['header'] = $this->load->view('common/header', '', TRUE);

        if(file_exists('template/common/home.tpl')) { 

            $this->load->view('template/common/home.tpl', $template);

        } else {

            $this->load->view('default/template/common/home.tpl', $template);

        }

    }

}
```

Now instead using `$data['items']  = array();` use `$this->data['items'] = array();`

and finally your home controller should be extended by `MY_Controller`

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
```

using _render() is easy

whenever you need to render page just do  `$this->_render();`

Comment: I would like to be able to still do if statement like above just need a would like to be able to use the if statement if possible trying to get it like way I have got just easier for me thats all

Comment: You dont pass any data to views? (also see I edited my answer to fit your needs)

Comment: Ok Just Made My Decision Giving Up On Codeigniter Not Really Working. Does Not Let Me Do What I Am After.